# How do I determine where `pub global activate` puts its files?

Tags: dart

Where does `pub global activate` install its packages? How do I use the `pub` tool to tell me that information?

Comment: There was this PR https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/1383/files from the Flutter team. Perhaps you want to reopen it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there anyone else besides Flutter developers who uses Dart?